# Use pseudo-element :before in UL to create a vertical line

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm creating a vertical menu that can have submenus. For these, I'm trying to add a vertical line with the use of CSS pseudo-element `::before` and `border`.

The issue that I'm facing is that CSS is being applied to the entire menu instead of the specific submenu.

I think the issue lies with the use of `position: absolute;`, but without it, the border is never displayed.

Below is the code and you can check the issue in this **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/r8kvqnLy/)**.

```
<ul id="test-ul">
    <li><a>one</a></li>
    <li>
        <a>two</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a>sub one</a></li>
            <li><a>sub two</a></li>
            <li><a>sub three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>three</a></li>
    <li><a>four</a></li>
    <li><a>five</a></li>
</ul>

<style>
    /* reset defaults */
    ul { list-style: none; }

    /* apply style to menu */
    #test-ul {
        background-color: #eee; 
        border-color: #ccc;
        position: absolute;
    }

    /* style links */
    #test-ul > li a {
        color: #2b7dbc;
        border-top-color: #e4e4e4;
        background-color: #fff;
        display: block;
        padding: 7px 0 9px 20px;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-top-style: dotted;
    }

    /* do CSS3 magic and show a vertical border on the left of each submenu item */
    #test-ul > li > ul::before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 18px;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border: 1px dotted;
        border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/d6tmLpy0/ or http://jsfiddle.net/k7xdma3e/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply give `.submenu` a position of `relative`

```
.submenu{
    position: relative;
}
```